# Global variable in express using mongo/mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Im using res.locals to have global variables using express.

**Example:**

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
    res.locals.success = req.flash("success");
    next();
});
```

How can I make something like:

```
Topics.find(); // Using mongoose
```

Find all Topics and then store it in a `res.locals` inside `app.use`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With something like

```
app.use(async function(req, res, next){
    try {    
        res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
        res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
        res.locals.success = req.flash("success");
        res.locals.topics = await Topics.find().lean();
        next();
    } catch (err) { 
        next(err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to cache the results of the find? If so just have a variable outside of the scope of app that contains the stored value. If you want to refresh the cached results just set an interval.